# Div with video element and unexpected scrollbar

Tags: html, css

In my app a div containing a video element should be as high as the parent and not show a vertical scrollbar. Sizing is done as follows:

- outermost div set to viewport height
- subsequent divs are set to 50% or 100% of parent height using bootstrap sizing utilities

The innermost div containing the video element has a scrollHeight larger than the clientHeight. Why is that and how can I get rid of the vertical scrollbar?

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/holger_grzonka/r781dmay/2/

**HTML**

```
<!-- limit outermost div to viewport height -->
<div id="screen-height">
  <div class="container-fluid h-50">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xl-2 h-100" id="file-list-div">
        <ul class="list-group h-100">
          <li class="list-group-item">Link 1</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- div with vertical scrollbar, even though styled as overflow outo -->
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xl-10 h-100" id="video-div">
        <video controls autoplay class="h-100">
          <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-04/large_watermarked/210329_06B_Bali_1080p_013_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `font-size: 0;` on the div containing the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `vertical-align` property to `top` for the video element.

Comment: vertical-align: top does the trick, thank you @j08691! I am still curious why, as the Inspector does not show any padding on the video element. In either case the video element is supposed to stretch to parent's height, but without vertical-align: top some extra pixels are added so that the parent div's scrollHeight exceeds the clientHeight.

Comment: display: block; also works